# Caching in service layer

Tags: .net, caching

We have an multi-layer app with service layer around business layer. As we have several presentation layers (asp mvc web, web api) we are interested in implement caching in service layer.
I would like to hear some recommendation about what cache framework (or built in solution) we might use, as web cache is not an option)?

Thanks

PS.
We use .NET 4.5

Comment: I'm assuming that you would like some kind of distributed cache such that cached data can be shared across your mvc and web api applications. There are numerous options for this. One that is relatively straightforward to get started with is using Redis for this, as Microsoft has done with their new Azure Redis Cache offering. You would likely want to host redis in your own infrastructure though to reduce latency

Comment: Thanks Russ!
One additional question...is Redis for distributed solutions only or is it a good option for having it on the same server as the client applications that use it?

Comment: PS. your assumption is right: my goal is to have one cache used by all clients instead of having all clients implementing own cache that i have to sync.

Comment: You could have it on the same server as the applications, yes. You may want to adjust the redis configuration file, particularly `maxheap` so that everything runs smoothly on one machine

Comment: Thanks!
That sounds nice and as a way to go. could you please promote your comment into answer so i can mark it as answer? [if you find anything else important to have on mind you can put it there]

Comment: I've added an answer and provided some additional information. Hope that helps.

Comment: You can also look into [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/) which is native .Net distributed caching solution. NCache also have  a free version [NCache Express](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/ncache-express.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you would like some kind of distributed cache such that cached data can be shared across your MVC and Web API applications.

There are numerous options for this. One that is relatively straightforward to get started with is using [Redis](http://redis.io/) for this, as Microsoft has done with their new Azure redis cache offering. You would likely want to host redis in your own infrastructure though to reduce latency.

If you're running on Windows, you can install the [redis nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Redis-64/) which will give you redis-server.exe, the redis server process, and redis-cli.exe, the command line interface, amongst other things. You can run redis on the same machine as the one on which your applications run; take a look at the Redis Release Notes.docx that's in the nuget package directory when you install the package for information about running redis on windows and also check out [Marc's posts on the subject](http://blog.marcgravell.com/2014/03/windows-redis-64.html).